# Doubled UITableViewCell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, synchronization, icloud

I use iCloud Sync in my app in combination with coredata. Sometimes it happens that data in my tableView is 2 or 3 times displayed so if I have 2 cells there are 4 or 6 cells displayed and every 2nd cell has the same content. Does someone knows why this happens and how to solve this?

My code:

```
func persistentStoreDidChange() {

    //load data
    //tableView.reloadData()
    loadData()
}

func persistentStoreWillChange(notification:NSNotification) {

    actvityIndicator.hidden = false
    icloudSyncLabel.hidden = false
    actvityIndicator.startAnimating()

    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = false

    let moc = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    //disable UI (changes in progress)
    managedObjectContext?.performBlock{ () -> Void in
        if moc.hasChanges {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.save(&error) {
                abort()
            }
            else{
                moc.reset()
            }
        }
    }
}


func recieveICloudChanges(notification:NSNotification) {

    let moc = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    moc.performBlock { () -> Void in

        moc.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
        self.loadData()
    }

    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = true

    actvityIndicator.hidden = true
    icloudSyncLabel.hidden = true
    actvityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your managed object contexts look a bit strange. In `..WillChange..` you get a reference to the fetched results controller's managed object context `moc`, but you use the block API on a different (optional) context, presumably a class instance variable. You need to clarify

- if the optional context is not `nil`
- if the optional context is the same as the fetched results controller's context (i.e., `moc`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I thought about it but don't really know how I can solve it. Could you please give me an example how I can check if the optional context is the same as the fetched results controller's context?